# scipy.integrate.quad Missing Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I know this sounds like I just need to input an 'a' and 'b' but as far as I can tell, my syntax looks correct. When hovering over the integrate.quad, PyCharm is telling me "Expected type 'float', got 'Tuple[float, float, dict, Any, Any]' instead."
When I run the code, it gives me a type error: "quad() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'."

Here's my code:

```
t0 = 1.
pt = 20.
p0 = .00002

pressRef = (pt**2)/(p0**2)

SEL = 10*log10((1./t0)*integrate.quad((pressRef, -inf, inf)))
print(SEL[0])
```

This is my first time writing an SEL function for Digital Signal Processing so, admittedly, I'm fairly new to integration in python.

Comment: You are passing a tuple to `quad`, so what PyCharm is telling you is quite correct. Drop the extra brackets around the arguments to `quad`.

Comment: Also reread the docs for `quad`.  The first argument should be a function.  `pressRef` is just a float.  You may need to practice with the examples in the docs.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much that helped! Guess I got parentheses happy. And I’ll definitely go back through them.